# JOptionPane Descending Array Program Issues

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, user-interface, joptionpane

So, I don't see any errors prior to running the program. Basically it's an array program in which the user enter 10 numbers. Once the user types the number of Arrays, it then just pops up a GUI where it says type in an Array of 10. It only lets you do it once, and it just repeats the same number the user typed 10 times. It's all jacked up and it doesn't help that I've only been doing it for several weeks while doing 12 hr shifts. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be awesome!

```
package Array;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response;
        response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the numbers : ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(response);
        int[] a=new int[n];
        int i,j,temp=0;
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter "+n+" Array Elements : ");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(response);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\nArray Elements Are : ");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"  "+a[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
                if(a[i]<a[j]) {
                    temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;          
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\nArray Elements in Descending Order : ");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"   "+a[i]);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all jacked up"?  What specifically is it doing wrong, and what should it be doing instead?  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you. Basically it won't let the user enter the number of variables for the array. And thanks, I'm a learner in progress when it comes to Java

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is, you're just not asking the user to enter a value for each element in the array and simply parsing the last `response`, which is the number of elements for the array.

I stripped back your solution and removed the `JOptionPane` as it's probably not the best solution to the immediate problem.  It wouldn't, however, take much to replace `Scanner` with `JOptionPane` as generally they are doing the same things

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Number of elements: ");
String response = input.nextLine();
int numberOfElements = Integer.parseInt(response);
int[] values = new int[numberOfElements];

for (int index = 0; index < numberOfElements; index++) {
    System.out.print("Element " + index + ": ");
    response = input.nextLine();
    int value = Integer.parseInt(response);
    values[index] = value;
}
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < numberOfElements; j++) {
        if (values[i] < values[j]) {
            int temp = values[i];
            values[i] = values[j];
            values[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Sorted:");
for (int index = 0; index < numberOfElements; index++) {
    System.out.println(values[index]);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this array using JOptionPane? I'm trying to specifically create it without using Scanner. But so far, you've been extremely helpful *MadProgrammer

Comment: Take `Scanner` out put `JOptionPane` in - the point is, in the first `for-loop`, you MUST be prompting the user for the next number, which your code isn't doing, the `JOptionPane` is just confusing the issue (IMHO) - I'd recommend, taking the time to understand the example and attempt to modify it yourself to use `JOptionPane` - you'll learn from the exercise then simply copying and paste someone else solution